# Batch file creating folders in all folders of current directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, directory

I am trying to create a simple batch file that runs in some directory and goes to "foldername data My documents" and creates a folder named "outlook archive

That's what I have for now... but I keep getting errors.

> FOR /D %% IN ("C:\Users\nhajjar.AMERICAS\Desktop\test*\Data\My documents\") do (MD Data)

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: think you need a parameter after the %%, before 'IN'

Comment: but this is a wildcard. All examples I have seen refer to a specific letter in the alphabet but I really want ALL folders, regardless of what the name is

Comment: I don't believe it is a wildcard. That parameter is what gets assigned to your various increments to perform the command(s). Leaving it blank means the for loop can't assign each increment to anything to perform the command.  On a side note, I do not know if the IN (...) portion will loop through folders, so I did not make a formal answer.

Comment: Any idea on what to put there instead then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Total rewrite of answer. This will make a "Outlook Archive" folder in only the Data\My Documents\ subfolders of wherever the batch file resides.

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /ad/s/b') do if EXIST "%%i\Data\My Documents\" MKDIR "%%i\Data\My Documents\Outlook Archive\"
pause
```

Credit to [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/05/11/2532913.aspx)

Comment: this only created that folder structure in the directory test (which worked for me).
what I am trying to do however is to check in each folder in the "test" directory, that folder structure (IF IT's not there)

Comment: Totally rewrote answer. When I reread the question (skipping the title), I forgot you needed a folder created in all subfolders.

Comment: hmmmm this gets closer to what I want but not quite there. It just created an "oulook Archive" folder in all subdirectories regardless of if there is "data and " My documents". It needs to create ONLY in Path\Data\My Documents\ if it's not there already. Makes sense?

Comment: Maybe I can give you an example. 
Three folders : A, B, C
Each of these folders has MANY subfolders in there but has for sure a Data folder (which btw can be upper or lowercase - not sure if that matters - I just want to avoid overwrite because it's not what im trying to do ). In each Data folder, There is folders such is "desktop" "favorites" etc. but we are looking for My documents (upper or lowercase, again, I don't want to overwrite the folder). 
Once in there, If there is an archive Oulook folder, then do nothing. Otherwise, create the folder.

Comment: I follow. I thought it strange to make that folder in ALL subfolders - new edit to try.

Comment: That's great. One downfall. If there is already an Outlook folder, it's creating another "outlook archive" subdirectory

Comment: ACTUALLY, NVM. I'm sorry for the last comment. You are correct. This worked. Just tested it. 
THANK YOU!

Comment: I have one more question. Can you explain  more in details the script?

Comment: I suggest reading the site I cited at the end of the answer, but the tricky parts are explained here:

'The dir /ad/s/b command performs a recursive listing of only directories, printing just the names of the directories found.

The option we provide, delims= changes the default delimiter from a space to nothing. This means that the entire line is to be read into the %i variable. (Normally, only the first word is assigned to %i.) Therefore, the FOR loop executes once for each subdirectory, with the %i variable set to the subdirectory name.'

Comment: ..continued.. The $$i is just the current folder here, so the "do" part is to look for when the current folder has your \data\my documents\ folder, and if so, make the outlook archive folder